# How can I use regex in python so that characters not included are disallowed?

Tags: python, regex

Here is the code:

```
import re
name = input("Enter a username: ")
y = len(name)
for i in range (0, y):
    valid = re.match("[A-Za-z0-9!£$%^&*]", name[i])
if valid:
    print("Username valid")
else:
    print("Username inavlid, try again")
```

When I enter a username containing the only the characters in the regex, it prints "Username valid", and when I enter one containing only characters not included, "Username invalid, try again" is printed.

However, when I enter a combination of allowed characters and characters that aren't allowed, the password is validated. How can I make it so that if even one of the entered characters is not in the regex, the program says that the username is invalid?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you last char is valid, the whole string is considered valid. You re-write the `valid` value each time. Use `valid = re.match(r'[A-Za-z0-9!£$%^&*]+$', name)`

Comment: Your `re` does not match the entire string, but only part of it. use `^[A-Za-z0-9!£$%^&*]+$` to match from beginning to end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantic error is that you keep overwriting the content of `valid` even when there has been no match on the character before.

Avoid the `for` loop altogether and change the regex to `"[A-Za-z0-9!£$%^&*]+$"`

Comment: @jbndlr `re.match` starts at the beginning, the ^ is not needed.

Comment: like this?                                                                                                      else:
    valid = re.match("[A-Za-z0-9!£$%^&*()-_=+]+$", password)
    if valid:
        print("Password valid")
    else:
        print("Password inavlid, try again")                                        Because it doesn't seem to work.